# d3.js Not able to Drag all rectangles

Tags: d3.js

I have build the below code to create a customer vertical slider that can be plotted in an x and y axis plot.

I have taken input from a csv file and then using it to build the below output in d3.js.The code in d3.js is as below :

**Edit 1:** I am currently able to drag only the yellow rectangles only, but not all the rectangles. [This is how the the modified graph looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgUqu.png)

Need your suggestions on -

1) How to drag all the rectangles individually
2) Keep the rectangle color belonging to a line same. For Example : all the rectangle with the first line will have same color and all the rectangles along the 2nd line will have another color and so on.

It will be of immense help, thanks !

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Data</title>
    <style>

        div.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 90px;
    height: 32px;
    padding: 1px;
    font: 11px verdana;
    background: rebeccapurple;
    color: white;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  .grid .tick {
    stroke: lightgrey;
    opacity: 0.7;
  }

  .grid path {
    stroke-width: 0;
  }
        svg {
  float: left;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-right: solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-right: -1px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

rect {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

svg {
  float: left;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-right: solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-right: -1px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

rect {
  opacity: 0.9;
}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function dragstarted(d) {
            d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
            d3.select(this).classed("dragging", true);
        }

        function dragged(d) {
            d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
        }

        function dragended(d) {
            d3.select(this).classed("dragging", false);
        }
        // load csv from the same directory
        d3.csv("test.csv", function (data) {

            data.forEach(function (d) {
                x_value: +data.x_value; // convert to number with +
                promotedprice: +data.promotedprice; // convert to number with +   
                nonpromotedprice: +data.nonpromotedprice;
                avgprice: +data.avgprice;
                brand: data.brand;

            });

            var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", 700)
                .attr("height", 450)


            // Attach the Promoted Price Rectangle    
            var g = svg.selectAll("rect")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("g")
                .classed('rect', true)
                .call(d3.drag()
                    .on("start", dragstarted)
                    .on("drag", dragged)
                    .on("end", dragended));


            var accent = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeAccent);

            /*.call(d3.drag()
                .on("start", dragstarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragend));*/

            /*g.append("rect")
                .attr("width", 18)
                .attr("height", function (d) { return (d.nonpromotedprice - d.promotedprice) + 100; })
                .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x_value; })
                .attr("y", function (d) { return (d.nonpromotedprice - d.promotedprice) / 2; })
                .attr("fill", "#E6EAEE")
            */
            g.append("line")          // attach a line
                .style("stroke", "gray")
                .style("stroke-width", 12)  // colour the line
                .attr("x1", function (d) { return d.x_value; })     // x position of the first end of the line
                .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.nonpromotedprice; })      // y position of the first end of the line
                .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.x_value; })     // x position of the second end of the line
                .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.promotedprice; });


            g.append("rect")
                .attr("width", 20)
                .attr("height", 15)
                .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x_value - 10; })
                .attr("y", function (d) { return d.promotedprice; })
                .attr("fill", "#F9EA55")


            g.append("rect")
                .attr("width", 20)
                .attr("height", 15)
                .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x_value - 10; })
                .attr("y", function (d) { return d.nonpromotedprice; })
                .attr("fill", "#ED8B00")

            g.append("rect")
                .attr("width", 20)
                .attr("height", 15)
                .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x_value - 10; })
                .attr("y", function (d) { return d.avgprice; })
                .attr("fill", "#28468E")
                ;


            g.selectAll("rect")
                .style('cursor', 'pointer');

            g.selectAll("text")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .insert("text", "line")
                .text(function (d) { return d.brand; })
                .style("text-anchor", "top")
                .style("fill", "red")
                .style("font-family", "Arial")
                .style("font-size", 34);

            function dragstarted(d) {
                d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);
            }

            function dragged(d) {

                d3.select(this).select("rect")
                    //.attr("x", d.x = d3.event.x)
                    .attr("y", d.y = d3.event.y);
            }

            function dragended(d) {
                d3.select(this).classed("active", false);
            }


        });



    </script>
</body>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Dilip, your snippet is not currently working. Fails with an error on forEach.

Comment: Hi Bibberty , It could be failing because it is taking input from a csv file. I will see if i can add the csv file here.